# problem changing UUID UBUNTU SERVER 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lvm

```
root@machinename:/dev/mapper# pvchange --uuid /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv".
  0 physical volumes changed / 0 physical volumes not changed
```

Ubuntu server installed with and filessystem configured as lvm. This server is a clone from another server.

```
root@machinename:/dev/mapper# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              391M  2.2M  388M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   48G  5.3G   41G  12% /
tmpfs                              2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop1                          90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/sda2                          976M  145M  764M  16% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              391M     0  391M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I did google a bit but I could not find a fast solution.
Any one has an idea? thx

Answer (score 0):

According to `man pvchange` you need to specify a physical device (for example `/dev/sda3`) in the `pvchange`-command, not a logical volume like `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`.

```
Synopsis

    pvchange [--addtag Tag] [-A|--autobackup {y|n}] [-d|--debug] [-f|--force]
    [--deltag Tag] [--metadataignore {y|n}] [-h|-?|--help] [-t|--test]
    [-v|--verbose] [-a|--all] [-x|--allocatable {y|n}] [-u|--uuid]
    [PhysicalVolumePath...]

-u, --uuid
    Generate new random UUID for specified physical volumes.

Example

    Disallows the allocation of physical extents on this physical volume (possibly
    because of disk errors, or because it will be removed after freeing it:

    pvchange -x n /dev/sdk1
```

Comment: How can i figure out which normal volume is the same as the logical volume>? /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

Comment: @wwi I think `lsblk -f` should show you something useful.